# I'm using the following code to obtain tweets from the twitter,How can I get the tweets alone from it?

Tags: python, twitter

In the variable `x` here I have all the contents in the page, But I wish to obtain the tweet texts alone. How can I do this?

```
from twitter import *

t = Twitter(auth=OAuth("1865941472-AbdUiX4843PBSkz0LwiLXlbbIPj20w9UQKYg5lY",
                       "WJ76T7i0PDotsP8C42F74hbhzbtUT5cxV3z9ZbcZCuw",
                       "lNhLOub6HsRm0sukRuyVA",
                       "QfwvN94uXX55rJ6b5tOCDwCUTfsHXnfxzxRf1Fgt1k"))
t.statuses.home_timeline() 
x = t.search.tweets(q="#pycon")
t.statuses.home_timeline()
print x
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with OAuth, but it looks like you've included passwords/keys in the question. If so I suggest changing them immediately.

Comment: Please also provide examples of the outputs of some of the data you're getting back.

Comment: Also, consider your credentials compromized from now on, and change them

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get tweets from your timeline:

```
home = t.statuses.home_timeline()
for i in range(len(home)):
    print home[i]['user']['name'] + ' (@' + home[i]['user']['screen_name'] + '): ' + home[i]['text']
```

You'll get output in this pretty style:

```
username (@userlogin): text of tweet
```

As default, home_timeline() returns 20 recent tweets. You may change number of tweets to count you want, using `home_timeline(count=cnt)`. Another way is using TwitterStream() instead of Twitter().

If you want to get tweets from search:

```
query = t.search.tweets(q="#pycon")
for i in range():
    print query['statuses'][i]['user']['name']+' (@'+query['statuses'][i]['user']['screen_name'] + ') wrote:', query['statuses'][i]['text']
```